# Magento 2 setup:staitic-content:deploy doesn't update css

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I'm running Magento 2 in **production mode**.

I made some changes in my theme's css files.

I try to make the css change reflecting on the live site, by using following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU en_US
```

I can't see the css files are updated in **pub/static** folder.

I have flushed cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` before and after static-content deploy.

Did i miss any steps?

---

Update,

By removing everything from the pub/static/frontend folder, then deploy static-content will make css changes reflecting on the site. But this will break site for a few moment. There's no way to implement css / js changes in a product mode without breaking the site?

Comment: Please try **Flush Javascript/CSS cache** from admin panel and then check. **@xxx**

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Before I deploy, I ran this command magento cache:flush. I think this will remove all cache?

Comment: First you execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. after that **Flush Javascript/CSS cache** from admin panel.

Comment: Working or not? **@xxx**

Comment: I tried to flush js/css cache i admin after static-content:deploy. The css files still not updated in pub/static/frontend folder. But if I remove everything from pub/static/frontend folder then deploy, it will work. but as I mentioned in the question, removing everything from pub/static will break my site for a few moment, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Deploy en_AU and en_US separately. and then check.

Comment: still no luck, I must still remove everything from pub/static folder in order to see css changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75137/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-xxx).

Comment: If it's a requirement that your site not be down during a deploy, there are other systems that you can integrate to make this happen. I haven't personally worked with them, but i know that lots of people have had success. A warning, these are not simple systems, and will take some time to learn and get working. https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-deploy-automation-using-capistrano-magento2/ and http://www.magenerds.com/2016/07/10/setting-up-magento-2-on-docker/

Comment: did you get solution ? please post here if you get the solution of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Run orders in the following order:

```
rm -Rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/*cache/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush --all
```

In **production mode**, you have a CSS and JS files cache, this cache is must remove after that is must refresh cache, [screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwJnSAe4ij1SsA71kO-C-o0RJJji2MeK/view).

Comment: If I remove everything from pub/static/frontend/* then my site will broke right? I know I can then deploy static-content right away, but I cant afford to have the site down for 1 or more minutes.

Comment: yes, after remove, site is possible to down, but you must remove everything from `var/view_preprocessed/`

Comment: Run commands from answer

Comment: thanks, but then we can come to a conclusion that when running Magento 2 in production mode, there's no way to get css / js changes on live site without breaking the site for a few moment?

Comment: I updated my answer, try now.

Comment: I see your updated answer about the css / js cache. but I ran cache:flush before deploy. doesn't cache:flush remove css/js cache?

Comment: this is command for clear all `php bin/magento cache:flush --all`, if not working, I recomand you to clear from admin and after that refresh to all caches.